# setting default data in django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i have this 2 models and i have a CreateModel2Form inside model1 DetailView , how can i set a model1 field default to the current One instead of selecting everytime the model1 field from a long list

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Model2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1 , on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class CreateModel2Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        fields = ['name', ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if "model1" in self.data:
            try:
                model1_id = int(request.GET.get("id"))
                self.fields["model1"] = Model2.objects.get(id=model1_id)

            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                print("ValueError, TypeError")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `initial`:

```
 self.fields["model1"].initial = Model2.objects.get(id=model1_id)
```